# How to get post content in javascript from markdown file

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

I am building a blog site with sveltekit and markdown. I import the .md file using dynamic import but i can only acces the metadata and not the post content written in markdown.
Please help

```
//[slug.js]
export async function get({ params }) {
    const post = await import(`../../posts/${params.slug}.md`)
    console.log(post.default)
    console.log(post.metadata)

    return {
        body: {
            postContent: post.default,
            meta: post.metadata
        }
    }
}
```

```
//[slug.svelte]
<script>
    export let postContent, meta
    const { title, date, thumbnail } = meta
</script>

<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{date}</p>
<img src={thumbnail} alt={title} />
<p>{postContent}</p>
```

Using post.metadata I can get the post title, date and thumbnail but post.default returns this:

`{ render: [Function: render], '$$render': [Function: $$render] }`

How can I get the post content?

Comment: Well it seems to have a render functions so you might wanna try `post.default.render()`

Comment: Thanks for the help @Reyno. I could get the post content using post.default.render().html but I found the solution to just use post.default on the endpoint and use <svelte:component this={postContent}/> on [slug].svelte to display the html

Comment: Maybe you can self-answer your question then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use post.default on the endpoint [slug].js and use <svelte:component this={postContent}/> on the [slug].svelte file.

Here are the files for the solution:

```
//[slug].js
export async function get({ params }) {
    const post = await import(`../../posts/${params.slug}.md`)

    return {
        body: {
            postContent: post.default,
            meta: post.metadata
        }
    }
}
```

```
//[slug].svelte
<script>
    export let postContent, meta
    const { title, date, thumbnail } = meta
</script>

<h1>{title}</h1>
<p>{date}</p>
<img src={thumbnail} alt={title} />

<svelte:component this={postContent} />
```